# swift weird tableview scroll behaviour from tableView header section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a weird tableview header behaviour when scrolling.

When I scroll up the header sticks on top of the view and a cell scrolls under the header.

If I scroll up more then the header starts scroll with the tableview.

Please have a look at GIF I added:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

And you can set content insets. Like this:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: <#T##CGFloat#>, left: <#T##CGFloat#>, bottom: <#T##CGFloat#>, right: <#T##CGFloat#>)
```

Comment: After your solution, my tableview is behind the navigation bar and i also lost the pull to refresh function, Any quick fix?

Comment: @Terry You can make the top of table view's frame under navigation bar. Or use `tableView.contentInset` as I post. Setting top of edge to 64.0 maybe works.

Comment: still struggling with contentInset. I tried to find a solution based on your answer...